# How can I prove that $\zeta(2n) = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I tried to prove this with Valli's equation:
$\frac{sinx}{x} = \prod(1-\frac{x^{2}}{(n\pi)^{2}})$ and use $\frac{d(ln(sin(x)))}{dx} = i + \frac{2i}{e^{2ix}-1}$.

Maybe it's better to use Taylor's transform?

The ended result: $\zeta(2n) = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382366/zeta2n-proof?lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome - the last link has an article with many nice proofs.