# How to derive the formula for Zeta function at even intergers

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Recently, I have been able to derive the power series for functions which contain the Bernoulli numbers, namely the $\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}$, $\cot(x)$, $\coth(x)$, $\tan(x)$, $\tanh(x)$. This leads me to consider the formula of Zeta function at even integers, which is:

$$(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{B_{2n}2^{2n-1}\pi^{2n}}{(2n!)}$$

I find this formula very interesting because many parts of it are similar to the kernels of those trigonometric and hyperbolic functions that I mentioned above.

Looking around, I can only find one elementary "proof" of this formula in [wikiproof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann_Zeta_Function_at_Even_Integers)

It is no surprise to me that the function $\pi x\cot(\pi x)$ is related to the  formula by the equation:

$$\pi x\cot(\pi x)=1-2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\zeta(2n)x^{2n}$$

But the proof of this formula looks kind of tricky. You add $-2$ and $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ to derive this formula.

There is another proof on [wikiproof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann_Zeta_Function_at_Even_Integers) which is much longer and use Fourier analysis to derive. This is way over my head and I don't think I can understand it at this moment.

I wonder if someone can list or provide resources for a simple and elementary derivation of this recurrent formula.

I have found some papers that I cannot access, one is:

[Another Proof of the Famous Formula for the Zeta Function at Positive Even Integers](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00029890.2018.1507206?scroll=top&needAccess=true)

[Euler's formula for the zeta function at the positive even integers](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.involve/1559181651)

If you have free access to these articles, may you mind share them with me?

Comment: Why do you call it "recurrent"? It is pretty well "explicit".

Comment: Here is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322604) asking the same.

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you, let me remove the word "recurrent".

Comment: The proof with the Cotatens isn't tricky, if you know the $sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(c^2+n^2)$ and expend it with the geometric series.

Answer (score 5):

$$f(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}-\sum_n \frac1{(z+n)^2}$$ is a $1$-periodic thus bounded entire function, [therefore it is constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)): $f(z)=f(i\infty)=0$.

Next expand $\sum_n \frac1{(z+n)^2}$ in Laurent series to make $\zeta(2k)$ appear and relate $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ to $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ to make the Bernouilli numbers appear.