# Need help on understanding a proof of the formula for calculating the $\zeta(2n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

[In this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322604/ways-to-prove-eulers-formula-for-zeta2n), Jack D'Aurizio provided a succinct proof for the formula of calculating the values of the Zeta function $\zeta(2n)$

> $$ \coth z-\frac{1}{z} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}.\tag{2}$$$$\begin{eqnarray*} \coth z -\frac{1}{z} &=& \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 1}}\frac{d}{dz}\log\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+z^2}\\&=&\color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2\color{red}{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}\color{red}{n^{2m}}} \\&=&\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$

> and we have the claim by comparing the coefficients in the RHSs of (2) and (3).

I just have a couple of questions regarding this derivation.

1. First, the sigma notation. I thought that the infinite product for $\sinh(x)$ is $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\color{red}{z}\left(1+\dfrac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$. So why there is a sum here, shouldn't it be a product? Also where does the $\color{red}z$ go?
2. How to prove, or how do we know that $\coth(z)-\dfrac{1}{z}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{d}{dz}\log\left(1+\dfrac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$. This is my guess. The derivative of $\log(\sinh(z))$ is $\coth(z)$. So that is why it is, am I correct?
3. I don't understand anything at all about the double sigma notation. I am always in fear of double sigma notation because I haven't learnt how to manipulate them well. So what was Jack doing here? Suddenly there are $(-1)^{2m-1}$, $z^{2m-1}$, $\pi^{2m}$
4. I don't understand anything when he says "comparing the coefficients in the RHSs of (2) and (3)." What should I suppose to do to understand this?

Comment: (1) I'm not sure which bit exactly you're talking about (2) yes; (3) try writing the summand as a geometric series; (4) compare the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ in both expansions.

Comment: @NoName could you post a fuller details in an answer, I still don't understand anything.

Comment: @NoName: My question is why there is a sigma notation instead of the product notation. Perhaps I miss some details here.

Comment: Because log turns products into sums, i.e. $\log(a_1a_2 \cdots a_n) = \log(a_1)+\log(a_2) +\cdots + \log(a_n)$

Comment: @NoName, ok I got it, so the term is going to be $\log(z)+\log(1+\frac{z^2}{\pi^2}) .etc$ Where is the $\log(z)$ in this case?

Comment: ad 4. $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}(-1)^{n-1}z^{2n-1}\color{red}{\Rightarrow} \frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}=\frac{2\,\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}(-1)^{n-1}$
$\Rightarrow \zeta(2n)= \frac{4^n\cdot B_{2n}\cdot  \pi^{2n}}{(2n)!\cdot 2}(-1)^{n-1}$.
But I´m not sure if the first implication (red) is true.

Comment: $$\sinh z=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \implies \log(\sinh{z}) = \log(z)+ \log\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) 
$$

I think your confusion is coming from that in your formula for $\sinh{z}$ you have the $z$ inside the product.

Comment: @NoName, thanks man. But in the answer of Jack, there is no $\log(z)$. There should be one, shouldn't there? I think he differentiate it to obtain $\dfrac{1}{z}$, then substract from $\dfrac{1}{z}$. Not sure if I am correct here.

Comment: Well if you rewrite it as $$ \log(\sinh{z})-\log(z) =  \log\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

Then differentiate both sides then $\log{z}$ becomes $\frac{1}{z}$ and the RHS becomes your first red sum.

Comment: @NoName, ok thanks man! Now the double sigma notation part really kills me. I am struggling to interpret it correctly.

Comment: The next step is using the geometric series $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+t} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}t^{m-1}$ as we've
$$ \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+z^2} = \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{z}{\pi n}\right)^2} = \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2} \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1} \left(\frac{z}{\pi n}\right)^{2m-2}$$

Which is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2} \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1} \frac{z^{2m-2}}{\pi^{2m-2}n^{2m-2}} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1} \frac{z^{2m-1}}{\pi^{2m}n^{2m}}$

Comment: @NoName, yeah I am also fumbling with your idea: I am trying to rewrite 

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{\pi^2n^2+z^2}=\displaystyle2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\pi^2n^2+z^2}$$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\pi^2n^2+z^2}$ can be rewritten as a geometric series, I have:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\pi^2n^2+z^2}$=geometric series formula

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're misunderstanding now. 

We've already shown that $$\displaystyle \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+z^2} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\color{blue}{2}(-1)^{m-1} \frac{z^{2m-1}}{\pi^{2m}n^{2m}}$$

(The blue 2 is missing in my last comment, can't edit anymore). Therefore  $$\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+z^2} = \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2\color{red}{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}\color{red}{n^{2m}}}$$

So we've already arrived at the double sum.

Comment: @NoName, thank you very much. I got the geometric part already. Now I am confused with the part where he says "and we have the claim by comparing the coefficients in the RHSs of (2) and (3).: $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}{\pi^{2m}n^{2m}}=\displaystyle\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}= \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}$. The equality is not so obvious to me.

Comment: I am substituting values into the expression to see if they are reduced to one another.

Comment: Sum over $n$ first

 $$ \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2\color{red}{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}\color{red}{n^{2m}}} = {\sum_{m\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 1}}\frac{2{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}{n^{2m}}} ={\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}} \bigg(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{2m}}\bigg) $$

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{2m}}= \zeta(2m)$, the sum becomes $\displaystyle \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}$ as required. 


For con. power series: $\sum a_n x^n = \sum b_n x^n \implies a_n = b_n $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ok I see, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{2m}}$ is indeed $\zeta{2m}$. It is that simple yet I keep banging my heads. Thank you so much. I wish I could upvote you but you didn't make a reply. The comments  cannot be modified easily so I can't do anything for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sinh z=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \implies \log(\sinh{z}) = \log(z)+ \log\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \\ \implies 
\log(\sinh{z})-\log(z) =  \log\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

Differentiating both sides we get $$\coth z -\frac{1}{z} = {\sum_{n\geq 1}}\frac{d}{dz}\log\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+z^2}$$

Next, we write the summand as an infinite series. Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+t} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}t^{m-1}$ we have $$\frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+z^2} = \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{z}{\pi n}\right)^2} = \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2} \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1} \left(\frac{z}{\pi n}\right)^{2m-2}$$

Which is equal to  $\displaystyle \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2} \cdot\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1} \frac{z^{2m-2}}{\pi^{2m-2}n^{2m-2}} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1} \frac{z^{2m-1}}{\pi^{2m}n^{2m}}.$

So we have $$\coth z -\frac{1}{z} ={\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}{n^{2m}}} $$

And summing over $n$ first we have
$${\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}{n^{2m}}} = {\sum_{m\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 1}}\frac{2{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}{n^{2m}}} ={\sum_{m\geq 1}}\frac{2{(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}}}{\pi^{2m}} \bigg(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{2m}}\bigg)$$

Since $$\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{2m}}= \zeta(2m)$$

We have

$$\displaystyle\coth z -\frac{1}{z} = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}.$$

---

So, on the one hand

$$\displaystyle \coth z-\frac{1}{z} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}$$
but on the other $$\displaystyle \coth z-\frac{1}{z} = \displaystyle \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}$$

So $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}(-1)^{m-1}z^{2m-1}$$

Reindexing the RHS  with $n$

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\,\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}(-1)^{n-1}z^{2n-1}$$

Then comparing the coefficient of $z^{2n-1}$ on both sides

$$\frac{4^n\,B_{2n}}{(2n)!} =\frac{2\,\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}(-1)^{n-1} $$

And finally solving for $\zeta(2n)$ gives:

$$\zeta(2n) = \frac{4^n\,B_{2n} (-1)^{n-1}\pi^{2n}}{2(2n)! } =\frac{\,B_{2n} (-1)^{n-1}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)! }$$

Comment: Upvoted! Thank you very much for your efforts and time. No words can express my gratitude.